# How does one in general analyze the convergence of the following series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

The following question is inspired in the following videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL43B1963F261E6E47

Say one has a general second order linear differential equation $y''+Qy=0$ for some functions $y,Q:U\subseteq\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with the initial condition $y(0)=a$ and $y'(0)=b$. Replace the equation by $y''+\epsilon Qy=0$ for $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}$. Assume the solution is of the form $y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}y_n(x)\epsilon^n$ for some functions $y_1,\dots,y_n:U\subseteq\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Then plugging in one finds:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}y''_n\epsilon^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}Qy_n\epsilon^{n+1}=y_0''+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(y_n''+Qy_{n-1}\right)\epsilon^n=0$$
Therefore, if we let $y_0(x)=a+bx$ and $y_1(0)=\dots=y_n(0)=y_1'(0)=\dots=y_n'(0)=0$ the initial conditions are fulfilled. Finally, one needs to solve $y_n''+Qy_{n-1}=0$ which has the obvious thanks to the initial condition of $y_n(x)=-\int_0^x\int_0^{s_{2n-1}}Q(s_{2n-2})y_{n-1}(s_{2n-2})ds_{2n-2}ds_{2n-1}$. The close form for $y_n$ is
$$y_n(x)=(-1)^n\int_0^x\int_0^{s_{2n-1}}Q(s_{2n-2})\int_0^{s_{2n-2}}\int_0^{s_{2n-3}}Q(s_{2n-4})\dots\int_0^{s_{2}}\int_0^{s_1}Q(s_1)(a+s_0b)ds_0\dots ds_{2n-1} \\
=(-1)^n\int_0^x\int_0^{s_{2n-1}}\dots\int_0^{s_1}Q(s_{2n-2})Q(s_{2n-4})\dots Q(s_{0})(a+s_0b)ds_0\dots ds_{2n-1} \\
=(-1)^n\int\limits_{[0,s_1]\times\dots\times[0,s_{2n-1}]\times[0,x]}(a+bs_0)\prod_{\{m\in\mathbb{N}^{\leq2n-2}|\text{m is even}\}}Q(s_m)ds_0\dots ds_{2n-1}$$
and the general solution would be
$$y(x)=a+bx+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\int\limits_{[0,s_1]\times\dots\times[0,s_{2n-1}]\times[0,x]}(a+bs_0)\prod_{\{m\in\mathbb{N}^{\leq2n-2}|\text{m is even}\}}Q(s_m)ds_0\dots ds_{2n-1}$$
Now, this solution does in fact work for $Q=0$ and $Q=1$ (in the latter the solution yields the taylor expansion of $\sin$ and $\cos$). Non the less, I am guessing that in most cases the solution diverges since otherwise it would be taught in any differential equations class. How does in general one examines the convergence of such a series? In which cases does the solution work? Is there any general rule to assure the convergence of the sequence?

Comment: In order to separate the scales as you've done, your are assuming $Q$ is $O(1)$. Also note that asymptotic series do not in general converge for all $x$, only in the limit $\epsilon\rightarrow0$.

Comment: What does it mean that $Q$ is $O(1)$?

Comment: If $Q$ was roughly the same size as $\epsilon^{-1}$, then you can't write your equation as $y_0''+\sum_n \left(y_n''+Qy_{n-1}\right)\epsilon^n$, it would be $y_n''+\epsilon Qy_n=0$ for each $n$, because $\epsilon Q~1$, so the $y_n''$ and $y_n$ terms balance.

Comment: I am sorry, can you please explain your point further? I didnt understand it

Comment: To split the equation up, you assume that something multiplied by a power of $\epsilon$ is smaller than anything multiplied by a smaller power of $\epsilon$, so you assume that $\epsilon Qy_n\ll y_n''$. But this is not true if $Q$ is very large, so your assumption is not correct.

Comment: No I didn't. I just renamed the indices in the sum to write it up nicely

Comment: You did, because the first equation you solved was $y_0''=0$. But if $Q=G/\epsilon$, where $G$ is $O(1)$, then the first equation to solve would be $y_0''+Gy_0=0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33023/discussion-between-ivan-mauricio-burbano-and-david).